# can't connect routes and models to controllers properly

Tags: ember.js

Seems like I have a disconnect in my app.

I think I'm following proper naming convention, but when I create a controller for a certain route, it kills the model which I've loaded in the route... it comes off as undefined in the template and in the controller.

My code is here:
https://github.com/mgenev/Full-Stack-JS-Boilerplate/tree/master/public/ember

I've tried to follow the guide for everything, I have no idea what's going on. If anyone can help me figure this out I'll really appreciate it.

**Update:**

It doesn't seem to matter whether I use an ArrayController or an Object one. No matter what I do, when I do:

> App.ArticlesCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  model: function () { 
>   return this.store.createRecord('article', {title: 'mah title',
>   pageContent: ''});  },  setupController: function(controller, model) {
>   this.controller.set('model', model); } });

i actually end up with undefined model in the back when I do setupController:

```
function(controller, model) { this.controller.set('article', model); }
```

I do have access to the article object in my controller and view –

Answer (score 0):

I only see one controller currently, so I'll guess off of that.

If your controller is backed by a model it should extend `ObjectController`, if it's backed by a collection it should extend `ArrayController`, if it's backed by nothing it should extend `Controller`.  The `ObjectController` and `ArrayController` proxy requests from the controller to the model/collection.

So if you have an ArticlesController backed by a collection it should be defined like so

```
App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

});
```

#### Update

there is no point in including setupController if all you're doing is setting the model on the controller, that's the default implementation of setupController.  You should also not do this.controller, you should use the reference sent into the method.

```
App.ArticlesCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
      return this.store.createRecord('article', {title: 'mah title', pageContent: ''});
    }
});
```

and update the controller to be an ObjectController

```
App.ArticlesCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   ....
});
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to matter. No matter what I do, when I do:

    App.ArticlesCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
       return this.store.createRecord('article', {title: 'mah title', pageContent: ''});
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controller.set('model', model);        
    }
});

i actually end up with undefined model in the back
when I do 

            setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controller.set('article', model);        
    }

I do have access to the article object in my controller and view

Comment: updated, next time throw your updates in your original question, they are easier to read up there (I just read it from your deleted answer, so all good)